# How do I find the last column with data?

Tags: excel, vba

I've found this method for finding the last data containing row in a sheet:

```
ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).row
```

Is there a similar method for finding the last data containing column in a sheet?

Comment: This might not work for Excel 2007+ workbook, which may have over a million rows.  You might want to use [`ws.UsedRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange(v=vs.80).aspx) instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I didn't know.

Comment: @ikh, its prob better to use `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy last column with data on specified row to the next blank column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.  The most reliable is find.

```
Dim rLastCell As Range

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

MsgBox ("The last used column is: " & rLastCell.Column)
```

If you want to find the last column used in a particular row you can use:

```
Dim lColumn As Long

lColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Using used range (less reliable):

```
Dim lColumn As Long

lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Using used range wont work if you have no data in column A.  See here for another issue with used range:

See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/excel-getting-the-actual-usedrange/7423252#7423252) regarding resetting used range.

Comment: + 1 readfidy :) A suggestion though... Always use `Application.CountA` with `.Find` to avoid errors. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column/11883425#11883425

Comment: Thanks @Sidd, you will find exactly that suggestion and additional info in the link I provided to Ozgrid in my comment above.

Comment: True :) I should have visited that link :)

Comment: @Sidd, it was still a good point though, and worth mentioning.  I just prefer not to post full answers with all error handling etc, I consider that to be doing there work for them, and in my interpretation that's outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Given there is a range object to work with testing for `Not Nothing` is a little cleaner than invoking a worksheet function. +1 btw Reafidy :)

Comment: @brettdj: Yup that also be can be used but if you are storing the lastcol in a variable then we can use the worksheet function as well. The other option would be to declare a range and then find the column if applicable. :)

Comment: @brettdj: I have added your suggestion to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column/11883425#11883425

Comment: Just make sure the filters are always clear, or this may not always give an accurate result. `If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData`.

Answer (score 20):

I know this is old, but I've tested this in many ways and it hasn't let me down yet, unless someone can tell me otherwise.

Row number

```
Row = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1] , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Column Letter

```
ColumnLetter = Split(ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Cells.Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
```

Column Number

```
ColumnNumber = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the code after you active the sheet:

```
Dim J as integer
J = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

If you use `Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row` only, the problem will be that the `xlCellTypeLastCell` information will not be updated unless one do a "Save file" action.  But use `UsedRange` will always update the information in realtime.

Comment: If you use this method with Column, it gives a wrong column.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can modify the `UsedRange` code from [@Readify's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795231/reafidy) answer above to get the last used column even if the starting columns are blank or not.

So this `lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count` modified to

this `lColumn = ws.UsedRange.Column + ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1` will give reliable results always

[image]

```
?Sheet1.UsedRange.Column + Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
```

Above line Yields `9` in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something which might be useful. Selecting the entire column based on a row containing data, in this case i am using 5th row:

```
Dim lColumn As Long

lColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox ("The last used column is: " & lColumn)
```

Comment: What makes your answer different then the accepted answer, besides being shorter? Also please avoid the use of the `Select` statement. That is really bad practice. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: it's short and simple and that's the value added. thanks for the tip on the Select statement. I will have a look. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [@Reafidy method/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11927387/5079799) for a long time, but today I ran into an issue with the top row being merged cell from A1-->N1 and my function returning the "Last Column" as 1 not 14.

Here is my modified function now account for possibly merged cells:

```
Public Function Get_lRow(WS As Worksheet) As Integer
 On Error Resume Next
 If Not IsWorksheetEmpty(WS) Then
  Get_lRow = WS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  Dim Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In WS.UsedRange
   If Cell.MergeCells Then
    With Cell.MergeArea
     If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row > Get_lRow Then Get_lRow = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
    End With
   End If
  Next Cell
 Else
  Get_lRow = 1
 End If
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function Get_lCol(WS As Worksheet) As Integer
 On Error Resume Next
 If Not IsWorksheetEmpty(WS) Then
  Get_lCol = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
  Dim Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In WS.UsedRange
   If Cell.MergeCells Then
    With Cell.MergeArea
     If .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column > Get_lCol Then Get_lCol = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Column
    End With
   End If
  Next Cell
 Else
  Get_lCol = 1
 End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple option if your data starts in the first row.

```
MsgBox "Last Row: " + CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Cells(1).EntireRow))
```

It just uses `CountA` to count the number of columns with data in the entire row.

This has all sorts of scenarios where it **won't** work, such as if you have multiple tables sharing the top row, but for a few quick & easy things it works perfect.