# How to find and select the last column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an excel macro which finds the last column of a sheet and then selects the entire column. However, this column will always be different- some days it will be column 'H', other days will be column 'GX' as the data in the sheet is constantly updated. So far I have seen how you can find the last column and then delete it, but it specifically refers to that certain column once the macro runs again. I need it to always refer to the last column, no matter what column that may be. Thanks!

Here is the code. I am new to VBA, etc. and this was created through the macro recorder and other things I found online so bear with me!

```
`Sub Macro11()
Sheets("Sheet25").Cells(1, 1).Activate
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
lastCol = ActiveCell.Column
Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub`
```

Comment: There are ample examples online for your post. Can you share the code you tried?

Comment: Yeah. I am new to VBA, etc. so I kind of used other posts I saw mixed with code from the record macro feature in excel. So bear with me.                                                                Sub Macro11()

'

Sheets("Sheet25").Cells(1, 1).Activate
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
lastCol = ActiveCell.Column

Columns("W:W").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub

Comment: `LastCol = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column where i is the row`  .Refer this [link](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: Doesn't that just find the last column in a certain row? I'm looking for it to select the entire column in the entire sheet, not just tell me how many columns there are in a certain row. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [excel vba finding the last column with data; Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926972/excel-vba-finding-the-last-column-with-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code
Avoid using Select /Activate in your code. To know why refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

```
Sub Macro11()
    Dim LastCol As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet25")
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Columns(LastCol).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If I wanted to do something similar- (find a column that is constantly changing and delete it) but instead of having it look up and delete the last column, have it use a 'find' (like ctrl+f) function to find a word in the spreadsheet and then select the column, would that be similar? Its another problem that I've yet to solve haha