# How to search data from two different sheets and copy them to a third sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

**Layout of Excel Sheets**
[image: Lay out of Excel Sheets]

**Problem:**

I have to find the superset of all strings from the first column of two sheets. These may be present in one or both sheets. Based upon the string which is present, copy that string to the third sheet. Then copy the data in the next column from one or both sheets. Then find out the difference. Repeat. This code works if the string is present in both the sheets. How do I make it work if the string in the first column is not present in one or both? I want to include all the data from the two sheets.

This is the code:

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Dim coli As Double
Dim Coli3 As Double
Dim rowy As Double

Dim numCols As Double
Dim startRow As Double
Dim lastRow As Double

Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

startRow = 6 'assuming data starts here
Coli3 = 2 ' start the columns out on ws3

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet3")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws3.Cells.Clear


'ws1.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=ws3.Range("A1")

'Find how many columns there are in sheet1 based on data in row 1
numCols = ws1.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For coli = 2 To numCols
    'Find last Data row in the given column in sheet1
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, coli).End(xlUp).Row

    For rowy = 6 To lastRow
        'perform calculation and place in the right spot on sheet 3
        If rowy = "6" Then
            ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3) = ws1.Cells(rowy, coli) & "-sheet1" ' copy sheet 1 to the right spot of sheet 3
            ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3 + 1) = ws2.Cells(rowy, coli) & "-sheet2" 'copy sheet 2 to the right spot of sheet 3
            ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3 + 2) = "Difference"
        Else
            If ws1.Cells(rowy, 1) = ws2.Cells(rowy, 1) Then
                ws3.Cells(rowy, 1) = ws1.Cells(rowy, 1)
                ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3) = Format(ws1.Cells(rowy, coli).Value, "#,##0") ' copy sheet 1 to the right spot of sheet 3
                ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3 + 1) = Format(ws2.Cells(rowy, coli).Value, "#,##0") 'copy sheet 2 to the right spot of sheet 3
                ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3 + 2) = Format((ws1.Cells(rowy, coli).Value) - (ws2.Cells(rowy, coli).Value), "#,##0")
            Else
                ws3.Cells(rowy, 1) = ws1.Cells(rowy, 1)
                ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3) = Format(ws1.Cells(rowy, coli).Value, "#,##0") ' copy sheet 1 to the right spot of sheet 3
                ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3 + 1).Value = 0 'copy sheet 2 to the right spot of sheet 3
                ws3.Cells(rowy, Coli3 + 2) = Format((ws1.Cells(rowy, coli).Value) - (ws2.Cells(rowy, coli).Value), "#,##0")
            End If
        End If

    Next rowy ' move to the next row on ws1, ws2, ws3

    'Since we are placing 3 cols at a time in sheet 3 we increment differently
    Coli3 = Coli3 + 3 '1 becomes 4, 4 becomes 7, 7 becomes 10 and so on

Next coli 'move to next column on ws1, ws2


End Sub
```

Please assist.

Comment: you are concerned with making sure if there is a value missing from either sheet 1 or sheet2 that the comparisons will continue?  It can be done.  !st we need to find the max rows of sheet 1 and the max rows of sheet 2 each time we move to process columns (perhaps they are not the same length each time), then we use the larger # as our loop counter.  We place an if statement in there that if one or the other is empty, simply make it 0, the difference will always be the non empty cell in that case(+ or -), or we could say "No diff" or "missing 1" or "missing 2", can doctor this up later.

Comment: I am slightly confused by you using strings, when it appears to be numbers and you are determining a mathematical difference.  Determining a difference in strings is a much different concept searching for a string in a string and reporting differences in chars before and after the found string . . . You are using numbers even if they are read as strings (like from an access read), you can still use them as numbers.  Right?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try. The strategy is to collect all unique string values in a buffer and store their row values in an index buffer (supposing one string occures only once on one sheet). Then take all row values from index buffer and copy values from that row to ws3. 
N.B.: i replaced the type of loop and lastrow counters to long.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Dim coli As Long    
Dim Coli3 As Long 
Dim rowy As Long    

Dim numCols As Long    
Dim lastRow1 As Long    ' last row on sheet1 in the actual data column
Dim lastRow2 As Long    ' last row on sheet2 in the actual data column
Dim r1stSheet As Range  ' string column range on sheet1
Dim r2ndSheet As Range  ' string column range on sheet2
Dim rFnd As Range       ' aux for search

Const MAXROW = 100      ' max number of rows
Const HDRROW = 6        ' row where the header is
Dim aStr(1 To MAXROW) As String    ' strings in col1
Dim aNdx(1 To MAXROW, 1 To 2) As Long  ' col1: row on sheet1 or 0, col2: row on sheet2 or 0
Dim iCnt As Long        ' last valid entry in aNdx

' Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

startRow = 6 'assuming data starts here
Coli3 = 2 ' start the columns out on ws3

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet3")

' Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws3.Cells.Clear

' make a unique list of all strings on sheet1 and sheet2

lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set r1stSheet = Range(ws1.Cells(6, 1), ws1.Cells(lastRow1, 1))
Set r2ndSheet = Range(ws2.Cells(6, 1), ws2.Cells(lastRow2, 1))
iCnt = 0

For rowy = HDRROW + 1 To lastRow1          ' process sheet1 against sheet2
    If ws1.Cells(rowy, 1) <> vbNullString Then
        iCnt = iCnt + 1
        Set rFnd = r2ndSheet.Find(What:=ws1.Cells(rowy, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        aStr(iCnt) = ws1.Cells(rowy, 1)
        aNdx(iCnt, 1) = rowy
        If rFnd Is Nothing Then         ' not found matching string
            aNdx(iCnt, 2) = 0
        Else                            ' match found
            aNdx(iCnt, 2) = rFnd.Row
        End If
    End If
Next rowy         ' on sheet1

For rowy = HDRROW + 1 To lastRow2            ' process sheet2 against sheet1: find nonmatching values
    If ws2.Cells(rowy, 1) <> vbNullString Then
        Set rFnd = r1stSheet.Find(What:=ws2.Cells(rowy, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If rFnd Is Nothing Then         ' not found matching string
            iCnt = iCnt + 1
            aStr(iCnt) = ws2.Cells(rowy, 1)
            aNdx(iCnt, 1) = 0
            aNdx(iCnt, 2) = rowy
        End If
    End If
Next rowy         ' on sheet2
rFnd = Nothing

For i = 1 To iCnt
    ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, 1) = aStr(i)   ' strings
Next i

'Find how many columns there are in sheet1 based on data in row 1
numCols = ws1.Cells(HDRROW + 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For coli = 2 To numCols
    ws3.Cells(HDRROW, Coli3) = "sheet1"   ' copy sheet 1 to the right spot of sheet 3
    ws3.Cells(HDRROW, Coli3 + 1) = "sheet2"   'copy sheet 2 to the right spot of sheet 3
    ws3.Cells(HDRROW, Coli3 + 2) = "Difference"

    For i = 1 To iCnt
        If aNdx(i, 1) = 0 Then
            ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3) = 0
        Else
            ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3) = ws1.Cells(aNdx(i, 1), coli).Value      ' val1
        End If

        If aNdx(i, 2) = 0 Then
            ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3 + 1) = 0
        Else
            ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3 + 1) = ws2.Cells(aNdx(i, 2), coli).Value  ' val2
        End If
        ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3 + 2) = ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3) - ws3.Cells(i + HDRROW, Coli3 + 1)        ' diff
    Next i

' finished with data, format columns
    Range(ws3.Cells(HDRROW + 1, Coli3), ws3.Cells(iCnt + HDRROW, Coli3 + 2)).NumberFormat = "#.##0"

    'Since we are placing 3 cols at a time in sheet 3 we increment differently
    Coli3 = Coli3 + 3 '1 becomes 4, 4 becomes 7, 7 becomes 10 and so on

Next coli 'move to next column on ws1, ws2

End Sub
```

Comment: I get subscript out of range error. Is there any way I can send you the input file?

Comment: I get it on this line: aStr(iCnt) = ws1.Cells(rowy, 1)

Comment: Can you have more than 100 rows? You might need to adjust the MAXROW constant. OR build in a check after iCnt=iCnt+1 like this: if iCnt>MAXROW then :  msgbox "Adjust MAXROW contant!" : exit sub : endif

Comment: determine the last row of each col as you are moving through, actually determine the last row on both sheets, so you can run with the larger and handle missing data along the way.