# How to find the last cell with a specifc format

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to find the last cell in a colum that contains a specific format?

Currently I use a for loop, below

```
LastRowNumber = Range("A:A").Find(What:="", after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 1 To 10000


            If Cells(LastRowNumber - i, 1).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss" Then

                LastRowNumber = LastRowNumber - i

            End If


Next i
```

This loop find the last cell in the column then search the cell above to see if its in the format of `[h]:mm:ss` however this just loops through until it fails when `i = LastRowNumber` is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/488132/excel-find-specific-number-format might help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the last cell containing the specific format, start to loop from the last used cell in the column:

```
For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "[h]:mm:ss" Then
        lastRowNumber = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Make sure to make `10000` a variable, based on the last used cell in a given column, if this is applicable - [Excel VBA- Finding the last column with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926972/excel-vba-finding-the-last-column-with-data)