# Dynamically find the sum values of range of cells in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Please how can find the Total Payment for each of the rows dynamically till the last non-empty row using Excel macro?

That is storing the sum of Cell ("B2", "C2", 'D2") in Cell("E2), the same with next row till the end non-empty row. See the above sheet.

Comment: How to find the last column (with data) has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11926972/19529102 - once you have the last column for a row it should be pretty straight forward from there: you could for example use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but i can't see any sheet here. Still i tried check this Macro if it works for you.

Sub Sum_Total_LastNONemptycell()

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Range("b1000000").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B" & i).Value, Range("C" & i).Value, Range("D" & i).Value)
Next i
```

End Sub