# Union multiple excel sheets. (Paste underneath each other)

Tags: vba, excel, union

What would be the cleverst way of copy and pasting Excel-Tables from multiple files to one single file. So espacially how do I determine the Range of the used Rows for the copy and paste within the makro?

Comment: The most simple way would be to loop through worksheets and find the last row ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba ) and last column ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column ) to identify the range and simply copy it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean *Tables* you can reference them using the `ListObjects` collection.

Try this (code located in destination workbook)
This code copies all source tables as separate tables with a blank row between.  If you want to merge the data into a single table you will need to copy `lo.DataBodyRange` rather than `lo.Range` and handle the header row and conversion to a table separetly.

```
Sub CopyTables()
    Dim wbFrom As Workbook
    Dim shFrom As Worksheet
    Dim shTo As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim clTo As Range

    ' Setup Destination for copied tables
    Set shTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DestinationSheet")  ' <-- change name to your destination sheet name
    ' remove any existing data
    shTo.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete
    Set clTo = shTo.Cells(1, 1)
    ' Loop through open workbooks
    For Each wbFrom In Application.Workbooks
        ' except destination wb
        If wbFrom.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            ' loop through all sheets
            For Each shFrom In wbFrom.Worksheets
                ' loop through all tables on sheet
                For Each lo In shFrom.ListObjects
                    lo.Range.Copy clTo
                    ' offset to next paste location, leave one empty row between tables
                    Set clTo = clTo.Offset(lo.ListRows.Count + 2, 0)
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Alternative inner For loop to paste to a single range

```
                For Each lo In shFrom.ListObjects
                    lo.DataBodyRange.Copy clTo
                    Set clTo = clTo.Offset(lo.ListRows.Count, 0)
                Next
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is a one time operation, probably the quickest way would be to activate the office clipboard (arrow in bottom right corner on *Home* tab). This allows up to 24 separate ranges to be collected and pasted below one another.

Assuming data is in one workbook and starts in row 2 on each sheet, as in the example below, you can:

- Select all the tabs
- Select all the rows on the first sheet
- Press Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Page Down, repeatedly to copy all the data
- Select a new sheet and click **Paste All**

Note that only the used range is copied so you can copy whole sheet ranges instead of needing to locate the last cell on each sheet.

[image]