# Write Data After Last Cell Used in a Row and do a vlookup going down the column until a certain cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to automate an excel process with vba.

There is a column for each month starting at 2010 (this can extend infinitely, or at least within excel's limit). There are some 500 rows below that with numerical data.

So, I would like to find the last column which isn't used (current month) and populate all of the rows under it from a vlookup.

Thanks.

---

Working Code!

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("IV42").End(xlToLeft)
    Dim iRow As Integer
    For iRow = 1 To 581

        Dim Lookup_Value, Table_Array, Col_Index, Range_Lookup As String
        Lookup_Value = "B42:B622"
        Table_Array = "'Current Rankings'!$B$2:$C$607"
        Col_Index = "2"
        Range_Lookup = "False"
        .Offset(iRow - 1, 0).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Lookup_Value & "," & Table_Array & "," & Col_Index & "," & Range_Lookup & ")"

    Next iRow
End With
```

Comment: Find last row, column, or cell: http://www.rondebruin.nl/last.htm

Comment: Another link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column/11883425#11883425

Comment: I saw a couple of these, but I think it is more complicated (or at least I am having trouble applying them).

Answer (score 2):

To find the last column, use `ActiveSheet.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft)`. (That is assuming you have values in the first row)

So, to find the column right after the last column used, you can use `ActiveSheet.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Range("B1")`. That will point to the first cell of the new month's column.

Then you can do a simple loop to fill the column...
Your code should look something like:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Range("B1")
    Dim iRow as Integer
    for iRow = 1 to 500

        Dim Lookup_Value, Table_Array, Col_Index, Range_Lookup
        Lookup_Value = ????
        Table_Array = ????
        Col_Index = ????
        Range_Lookup = ????

        .Offset(iRow-1,0).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & "," & _
            Lookup_Value & _"," & _
            Table_Array & "," & _
            Col_Index_Num & "," & _
            Range_Lookup & ")"

    next iRow
end with
```

Comment: I got this working. Posted the source above. Thanks @FlatEarch!