# VBA code to find max of last used column index within the selected rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where there are many rows. I need to get the max column index of the last non empty column within a specified selected rows range.

for example, the sheet contains 200 rows, each row contains 26 columns, but currently only rows 20 to 30 are selected. I need to find the maximum last used column index within these rows.

Please note that there can be empty cells in between non-empty cells in a row. I need to consider the last non empty cell only.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column Instead of `ws.Cells`, you can specify relevant rows as your range.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:
Assume you want to get the last column within the range `"A2:X50"` in `Sheet1`

```
Dim LastColumn as Long    
lastCol = Sheets(1).Range("A2:X50").Columns.Count
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout brain freeze :$ I still don't get it.. All I know this gives columns between the range specified `A2:C10` is 3 then `B2:C10` is 2.. I saw your link, I thought of giving the same, but I guess I was mislead here *max column index of the last non empty column within a specified selected rows range* :)

Comment: The OP already knows there are 26 columns :) What he wants is to find the last column in the rows 20-30 which has data. Note it is not necessary that Col X in your example may have data :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, lngMaxColumIndex  is the last column index and lngMaxRowIndex  is the last row index

Sub pFindLastCells()

```
Dim rngRange                As Range
Dim wksWorksheet            As Worksheet
Dim lngMaxColumIndex        As Long
Dim lngMaxRowIndex          As Long

'Set 'Sheet1' worksheet
Set wksWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With wksWorksheet
    'Check for last non-empty cell
    Set rngRange = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
End With

If Not rngRange Is Nothing Then
    'if found then assign last non-empty cell row and colum index to the variable
    lngMaxColumIndex = rngRange.Column
    lngMaxRowIndex = rngRange.Row
Else
    'if not found gives message
    MsgBox "No Data in " & wksWorksheet.Name, vbCritical + vbInformation, "Error"
End If

Set rngRange = Nothing
```

End Sub