# Copy and paste last used column into next available column

Tags: excel, vba

I know this has probably already been answered but I have searched through the previous questions and cannot find an answer that works for me.

Basically I have an excel spreadsheet which can be updated daily/weekly/monthly depending on the workflow. What I need is a macro that finds the last 'used' column(Headers are in row 5), inserts a blank column directly to the right of that - (we have a totals table at the end that needs to move along) & copies the entire last used columns data into that newly created column.

It's probably quite a simple code but I've only just started using VBA and hope someone can help!! I'm hoping once I've started doing some bits and pieces I can build up my knowledge!

Thanks in advance

Emma

Comment: `It's probably quite a simple code` - code it. This is a Q&A site we answer questions about the code you already wrote. This is not site where people request code and programmers write it for them. try flagging your own question and see how many flags you can raise against it. If you want help then do some research, show your current code and specifically say what is not working,

Answer (score 2):

From here:  [Copy last column with data on specified row to the next blank column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883256/copy-last-column-with-data-on-specified-row-to-the-next-blank-column) and here: [Excel VBA- Finding the last column with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926972/excel-vba-finding-the-last-column-with-data)

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim LastCol As Integer

    Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    LastCol = rLastCell.Column

    ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Lazy minimalist solution:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim col As Integer
col = Range("A5").End(xlToRight).Column
Columns(col).Copy
Columns(col + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

Though this will crash if there's nothing in cell A5.

Answer (score 0):

Sub LastColumn()

```
    Dim LCol As Integer
    LCol = Range("C3").End(xlToRight).Column
    Columns(LCol).Select
    Columns(LCol).Copy
    Columns(LCol + 1).EntireColumn.Select
    Columns(LCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

End Sub